# Differentiation minimization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization

This question taken from web based engineering mathematics online test.
[image: Question]

My answer to this question as below. This system says it is incorrect. Is there any mistake? Plz help.

[image]

Comment: Is this a test you are currently taking or is it a practice test?  It would be inappropriate to be asking questions about a test you are currently taking ...

Comment: @almagest I have edit the question.

Comment: You were asked to round up your answers to three decimal places.

Comment: @michael Burr This is a practice test

Comment: The question asks for three decimal places.  Also, I would be quite cautious about rounding $x$ in the middle of the problem; this can induce round-off errors.

Comment: @almagest x=3.4698... after round up x=3.470  so the minimum s is 108.361(after round up) I'll check it again.